# How to change "AgendaDay" day title format in fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, fullcalendar, momentjs

My question is as simple as the title.
I want to customize the format of the default title of AgendaDay view in the fullcalendar javascript library.

I've searched the whole documentation [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/).

I tried `titleFormat` attribute but no avail.

[image]

Is there anything that can do the trick ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try

columnFormat

Determines the text that will be displayed on the calendar's column headings.

format string/View Option Hash, default:

```
{
month: 'ddd',    // Mon
week: 'ddd M/D', // Mon 9/7
day: 'dddd'      // Monday
```

}

Comment: solved using : columnFormat: {
                        day: 'dddd DD/MM/YYYY'
                    }